# How to use forEach when there is no array [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript

I would like to use `forEach` in JavaScript.

`sentence.forEach(function(value) {--------`

When `sentence` is an array, forEach works properly.

```
{
    "sentence": [
        {
            "word": [
                {
                    "content": "tell"
                },
                {
                    "content": "me"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "word": [
                {
                    "content": "do"
                },
                {
                    "content": "you"
                },
                {
                    "content": "want"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when `sentence` has only one value and is not an array, forEach doesn't work and it makes error message like this. `Uncaught TypeError: sentence.forEach is not a function`

```
{
    "sentence": {
        "word": {
            "content": "hello"
        }
    }
}
```

I get json object from external API, so I don't know whether `sentence` has only one value or many values. How can I solve this problem? Could you give me any information or advice?

Comment: APIs that sometimes return an array and sometimes return a single object should be taken out and shot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you always have an array, and convert it to an array if it isn't. You could do something like the following:

```
const sentenceArray = Array.isArray(sentence) ? sentence : [sentence];
```

Then use sentenceArray instead like so:

```
sentenceArray.forEach(...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I have a question. `? sentence : [sentence];` What does this mean? Does this mean that if `sentence` is not an array make `sentence` an array?

Comment: @KazuakiSuzuki Basically, yes. if sentence is an array it will just use the sentence value 'as is', otherwise it will produce an array with a single element in it by doing `[sentence]`. If this way of writing a conditional assignment is unfamiliar to you, you could have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: @atarhan Thank you for your quick reply. I understand.

Answer (score 4):

You could convert the data to an array with [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) if it is no array or keep the array.

```
[].concat(data).forEach(callback);
```

For using this approach, you could wrap it in a function `getArray`.

```js
const
    getArray = value => [].concat(value),
    callback = ({ word }) =>
        getArray(word).forEach(({ content }) => console.log(content)),
    a = { sentence: [{ word: [{ content: "tell" }, { content: "me" }] }, { word: [{ content: "do" }, { content: "you" }, { content: "want" }] }] },
    b = { sentence: { word: { content: "hello" } } };
    
getArray(a.sentence).forEach(callback);
getArray(b.sentence).forEach(callback);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Could you tell me the relationship between `sentence` and `[].concat(data)` ? How can I use `[].concat(data)`?

Answer (score 1):

Split your code conditionally

```
if(Array.isArray(sentence)
{
 //your foreach
}
else
{
 //pick relevant properties from sentence object
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, it is an equally effective method.